# Manage session in a complete JSP project

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I am developing a shopping inventory system in simple JSP, Servlet. When I login with a user_id and password, I am doing session.setAttribute("admin",admin).
Then I am redirecting the page to Wholesaler.jsp, where I am doing session.getAttribute("admin) and I am getting the session value fine. But the PROBLEM is, whenever I click on the link of that Wholesaler.jsp page, it redirects me to login page.
PLEASE HELP !!
CODE for login page,

```
<%    
if(!password.equals(rs.getString("password"))){

%>
<jsp:forward page="admin_login.jsp">
<jsp:param name="msg" value="Invalid Authentication !! Try Again"/>
</jsp:forward>
<%  }
else{
session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("admin", admin);

db.close_connection();

%>

<jsp:forward page="/Wholesaler Transaction"/>
<%   }
```

CODE in wholesaler.jsp.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="true"%>

<%
if(session.getAttribute("admin")==null){
response.sendRedirect("/SMS/");
}
else{   //LOAD THE PAGE }
%>
```

Thanks IN Advance Guys..

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using password to validate in the wholesale.jsp. check it out. the password field must be empty the next time you click the wholesaler.jsp page

```
 if(!password.equals(rs.getString("password"))){
```